# My data insertion system in django does not work

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I will explain my problem :

I'm working on a commentary system, but I do not succeed at insert my datas in the table.

I possesses an formulary based on my model in the file forms.py,  then in my file views.py an function for treat the datas of my input textarea, then a html file with a field textarea, here is my code :

models.py :

```
class Commentary(models.Model):
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True))
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)  
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

forms.py :

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    contents = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=500, required=True)
```

views.py :

```
def createComment(request):
if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            commentary = form.save(commit=False)
            author = request.user
            commentary.contents = contents
            commentary.author = author
            commentary.created_at = timezone.now()
            commentary.save()
        return redirect('/home')
```

read.html :

```
<textarea name="contents" required id="contents"></textarea>
```

I looked on the forum and in the documentation of Django, alas nothing is stock, my way is it good?
Thanks all!

Comment: Do you get an error or it just doesn't save the data?

Comment: This code is never being called. If it was, you would get several errors - you don't *call* the `form.is_valid()` method, and you don't define `contents`. Your form has an empty `action` attribute, so it is being submitted to the same place that renders it in the first place, which again is not this code because there is no non-POST block.

Comment: Ah ! Ok, I see, so I need to create a new URL in urls.py that will be associated with my form processing function, then I put the path in the action attribute of my form? I thought Django could do it alone

Answer (score 0):

The part you're missing is the need to use a `ModelForm`.

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Commentary
        fields = ['contents']
```

Some other general tips:

- don't use `null=True` for `CharField`s
- `is_valid` is a method, not a property, so you need to do `if form.is_valid()`
- you only want to `redirect` if the form is valid, otherwise just let the template render with that bound form instance so that you can display any errors

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time, and your advice, alas, it does not work.
I am a little lost, I apply your advice, my formulary is good ? => https://pastebin.com/NyCYa7r4 . Again thank you for helping me